# Pulling out specific column when sometimes, the array is empty

Tags: arrays, matlab, zero

I am trying to pull out a column from inside a cell. However, sometimes, the cell is empty.

For example, if in this line, I try to pull out the last column inside PM25_win{i}, it sometimes has an array inside of size nx28. However, sometimes, the array is zero.

```
for i = 1:length(years)-1
    PM25 = table2array(PM25_win{i}(:,end));
end
```

When the array is empty, the code stops and I get the error

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

How can I account for both cases so that the code will simply create the PM25 variable as an empty array if PM25_win{i} is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add an if-else statement in the for loop.

```
for i = 1:length(years)-1
    if isempty(PM25_win{i}(:,end))
      PM25 = [];
    else
      PM25 = table2array(PM25_win{i}(:,end));
    end
end
```

Comment: Suggestion.  Don't add JavaScript formatting blocks in your code.  They don't work with MATLAB syntax and it detracts from the quality of your code.

Comment: The `isempty` line is still giving me the `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.` error since PM25_win{1} is `[]`.

Comment: then you just remove the ((:, end)) in the end of your line